# Unexpected element (uri:"", local: "element"). Expected elements are <{}link> <{}size>

Tags: java, jaxb, eclipselink, jaxb2, moxy

When trying to unmarshall this xml:

```
<holder>
  <name>a</name>
  <elements>
    <element>
      <name>elem</name>
    </element>
  </elements>
</holder>
```

I get the error `unexpected element (uri:"", local:"element"). Expected elements are <{}link>,<{}totalSize>` in the `ValidationEventHandler` and the tag `<elements>` (and therefore the `elements` field in `Holder` class) is ignored.

When generating the `XML` both `link` and `totalSize` are not outputted as they are nil.

**JAVA MODEL**

The hierarchy is a bit complex:

(Simplified for the sake of the question)

**ElementRoot**

abstract `ElementRoot` has the link member

```
public abstract class ElementRoot implements Serializable {

    protected String link;

    @XmlElement(name = "link")
    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

}
```

**Wrapper**

abstract Wrapper extends ElementRoot and has the totalSize member

```
public abstract class Wrapper<T> extends ElementRoot {

    protected int totalSize;

    protected List<T> collection = new ArrayList<>();

    @XmlElement
    public int getTotalSize() {
        return totalSize;
    }

    public void setTotalSize(int totalSize) {
        this.totalSize = totalSize;
    }

    public abstract List<T> getCollection();
}
```

**Holder**

Holder extends ElementRoot

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "holder")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"name", "elements"})
public class Holder extends ElementRoot {

    private String name;

    private Elements elements;

    // setters and getters not annotated
}
```

**Elements**

Elements extends Wrapper and has a collection of Element

```
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "elements)
public class Elements extends Wrapper {

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name="element")
    public Collection<Element> getElements() {
        return elements;
    }

    // No setter, to add getElements().add(element)
}
```

**Element**

Element extends ElementRoot

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "element")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "name"})
public class Element extends ElementRoot {

     private Integer id;

     private String name;

     // setters and getters no annotated

}
```

**ENVIRONMENT**

I'm using `java 7`:

```
JAXB-api 2.2.7
MOXy 2.5.0
```

Comment: I have added some model classes to your question based on your description.  How do you have these classes annotated?  Also where should the element `datastore` appear in your XML input?

Comment: `datastore` was left over from the original, I simplified the hierarchy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a bug in [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) for this use case related to the abstract `getCollecion` property.  We have opened up the following bug that you can use to track our progress on this issue:

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/411408

**WORK AROUND**

***Wrapper***

We can use `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)` so that only annotated fields/properties will be processed (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html).

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public abstract class Wrapper<T> extends ElementRoot {

    protected int totalSize;

    protected List<T> collection = new ArrayList<>();

    @XmlElement
    public int getTotalSize() {
        return totalSize;
    }

    public void setTotalSize(int totalSize) {
        this.totalSize = totalSize;
    }

    public abstract List<T> getCollection();

}
```

***Elements***

Since `@XmlAccessorType` is inherited by the subclasses we will specify `XmlAccessType.PUBLIC` to return things to normal.  Note:  I assume the `getElements()` method in your question should have been `getCollection()`.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name = "elements")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PUBLIC_MEMBER)
public class Elements extends Wrapper {

    @Override
    @XmlElement(name="element")
    public List<Element> getCollection() {
        return collection;
    }

    // No setter, to add getElements().add(element)
}
```